# How Does `case AsyncGenerator():` Work in Python's `match` Statement Without Raising an Exception?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pattern-matching, abstract-class

I'm seeking clarity on the use of abstract classes within Python's `match` statement, specifically the `AsyncGenerator` from the `collections.abc` module. In a `match` statement, using `AsyncGenerator()` in a `case` pattern confuses me as it resembles an instantiation of the abstract class.

For example:

```py
>>> from collections.abc import AsyncGenerator
>>> AsyncGenerator()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class AsyncGenerator with abstract methods asend, athrow

>>> async def check_generator(gen):
...     match gen:
...         case AsyncGenerator():
...             print("It's an AsyncGenerator")
...         case _:
...             print("It's something else")
...
>>> async def gen():
...     yield "something"
...
>>> await check_generator(gen())
It's an AsyncGenerator
>>>
```

This code doesn't raise any exceptions when I run my project, yet when I try to instantiate `AsyncGenerator` directly in the Python REPL, it does:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class AsyncGenerator with abstract methods asend, athrow
```

I'm trying to understand:

1. How does Python interpret `case AsyncGenerator():` in a `match` statement? Is it not an attempt to instantiate `AsyncGenerator`?
2. Why does this pattern not raise an exception in the `match` statement context, whereas directly instantiating `AsyncGenerator` in the REPL does?
3. Is there a specific design reason or advantage behind this syntax choice for pattern matching with abstract classes?

Any explanations or insights on this behavior would be greatly appreciated, as it seems to be a peculiar aspect of Python's pattern matching I haven't fully grasped yet.